# Is there a way to comment SQL queries in Sparx Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to comment SQL queries in Sparx Enterprise Architect e.g. /* SQL Query */. This is so that I can run different queries without having to delete previous queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query editor recognizes both `--` and `/* */`, but neither seems to actually work. So no.

Best way is to store your queries as searches.

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise Architect's #DB=# macro works well for comments in SQL Model Search queries.

```
#DB=COMMENT# <comment text> #DB=COMMENT#
```

For example, to explain why a query differs for JET4.0 vs. MYSQL versions:

```
SELECT distinct o1.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID,
    o1.name AS Name,
    o2.name AS Subtype,
    o3.name AS Sub2,
    o4.name AS Sub3,
    o5.name AS Sub4
#DB=COMMENT# JET does not allow mixing LEFT/INNER JOINS #DB=COMMENT#
#DB=JET#
FROM  <complex join, JET version>
#DB=JET#
#DB=MYSQL#
FROM  <complex join, MySQL version>
#DB=MYSQL#
WHERE
    o1.object_type = 'Class'
    AND o1.name LIKE '#WC#<Search Term>#WC#';
```

Comment: Just be aware that you shouldn't put #DB=COMMENT# My comment #DB=COMMENT# in the very beginning of your query.  From the book “Inside Enterprise Architect”, https://leanpub.com/InsideEA: “It seems that EA reacts strange to such comments appearing at the very beginning of a SQL. That means it does not issue any complaint but silently ignores anything. No error message, no result!” This behaviour is still valid for EA 16.1.

Comment: Some additional info: according to https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.1/the_application_desktop/creating_filters.html: “In the WHERE statements you can use #xxx# macros as string replacers”. So the fact that these macros are recognized only in WHERE statements probably explains why this hack does not work on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Comments with `--` and `/* */` are working in Enterprise Architect if the comment is **not** in the **first line**.